# How to convert attr to executable code? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="text" name="borderColor" id="myInput">

var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

document.getElementById('selector').style.myInput.name= "(style value)";
// want to use the .name attr after style here
```

Checked something about `eval()`, but seems not the right thing. Please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `document.getElementById('selector').style[myInput.name] = "(style value)"`

Comment: To access attribute, use [`Element#attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes). To access the value, use `value` attribute of input element. I don't see why you would need to actually execute any code.

Comment: Thank you very very much t.niese :)